# java.net.connectexception connection refused (connection refused) : not able to connect to local rabbitmq from docker container

Tags: java, docker, rabbitmq

Hi i am running a application in docker container and trying to connect to local rabbitmq server from docker container.But i am not able to do.

I have tried many solutions but could not get success in this.

rabbitmq credentials -

> host - 127.0.0.1,  port - 5672,  user - "guest", password -  "guest"

I am getting this error :

> java.net.connectexception connection refused (connection refused)

Please help here somebody!

Comment: Is RabbitMQ in another container, or on the host?  127.0.0.1 in Docker almost always means “this container” (not the host outside of Docker or any other container) so you’ll need some different name there.

Comment: @DavidMaze , rabbitMQ is locally setup. and  i am inside docker container and running a java program and want to connect to rabbitMQ(in local machine) from there.

Comment: 'Connection refused' means that nothing was listening at the target IP:port. So either it is wrong or the listening process hadn't been started.

Answer (score 1):

What’s the IP you are using to reach the rabbitmq instance ?

Do not use 127.0.0.1 from within the container.

If your host on which the containers running is say 192.168.x.y , ping this IP from the container and see if  it’s reachable.

If your host IP is reachable try ‘telnet hostip 15672’ to see if rabbitmq is reachable on the host IP on 15672 port.

All good ? Then try to connect to rabbit from container on hostport:15672

Still issues check the firewall rules and allow all internal routes to 5672, 15672, 25672, 4562 on which erlang, epmd, etc are listening

Answer (score 0):

Your host OS and container use different network namespace, so `127.0.0.1` in the container is not the same address `127.0.0.1` as you have in the host OS.

So:

- start you app container in host OS network namespace `--net=host` (I recommend to read doc and consequences of this config)

OR

- connect from the app container to the (non localhost, non 127.0.0.1) host OS IP, where RabbitMQ is listening